# Index of a specific row with Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Given a specific **Hibernate Criteria** which can be projected to a property called `"id"`, I want to find out the **list index of a row with a specific id**.

Using SQL (Oracle), I can solve this with an outer select, resulting in the row number (starting with 1) which I then can use to calculate the index (empty result set: `-1`, non-empty: `r-1`).

```
select r from (select rownum as r, id from whatever) where id = 12345
```

*Note: the rownum pseudo column is Oracle specific.*
Can I solve this somehow with the Hibernate Criteria API (using a custom projection/transformer, or whatever magic necessary), to apply this mechanism to an arbitrary Criteria?

Answer (score -1):

The ordering of rows returned can't be guaranteed unless you specify "order by"; in databases other than oracle (and maybe oracle as well) and also hibernate.

If an order-by clause can be supplied, you can then simply use the [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) in returned collection. Assuming id and hashcode are set up as expected.

For pagination with hibernate criteria, just use :

```
criteria.setMaxResults(10); 
criteria.setFirstResult(20);
```

And adjust the parameters accordingly ... the example returns 10 rows, starting at row 20.

So in your example, whichever criteria query returned the id - use indexof on returned collection, then add that result to the setFirstResult() parameter, and you'll have the index of row in database.

Or if you are not going to change from oracle, there is always a nativequery.

Comment: This returns just the number of rows (count(*)), please read the question again.

Comment: The actual queries I'm dealing with are ordered, but even then I can't find out the index by manipulating the query? The point is that I have large data sets with I load using pagination, and I need a non-expensive operation to find the index of a known row (by id), so I can't just load the whole data set into memory. I had hoped that I can somehow wrap the row selection SQL (see question) around the query generated by the hibernate (by means of a custom projection or something alike)...

Comment: I'm already using first/max results. Let's say I have a large number of records which match my criteria. If I'd know the correct page, I could indeed load that page only and find out the index of the desired row by using indexof, but the problem is I don't know *which* page contains my row (I would still need to read *each* page until I find the correct one, or I would need to know the index to find out the correct page).

Comment: @PeterWalser I would refactor the code to so that you can look up by page number and id, or just use a nativequery http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html

Comment: Unfortunately, as we already use Hibernate Criteria for all our complex searches, we cannot simply change them just for this one feature. Seems like there is no (efficient) solution which would work with Hibernate Criteria, but nevertheless, thanks for your efforts, I'm granting your the bounty :)